# How to obtain the minimum value of equation 6.7 in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, Bishop

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis

Equation (6.5), with $a$ and $t$ are vectors, K is a symmetric matrix, and $\lambda$ is real value.
$$
J(a) = 0.5 a^T KK a - a^T K t + 0.5 t^T t + 0.5 \lambda a^T K a
$$
The book provide the minimum solution,
$$
a = (K + \lambda I)^{-1} t
$$

I derived the gradient of (6.5) with respect to a as below,
$$
J^{'}(a) = a^T KK - Kt + \lambda a^T K
$$
and set the gradient to zero to find the minimum solution, but it does not look like the provided solution,
$$
a = (KK + \lambda I)^{-1} (Kt)^T = K^-1 (K + \lambda I)^{-1} t^T K
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the gradient you mix row and column vectors
$$J^{'}(a) = KKa - Kt + \lambda Ka =K((K+\lambda I)a-t)=0$$
If $K$ is invertible, you get $(K+\lambda I)a-t=0$.

Comment: If I choose to view the gradient as a row vector, what should be changed to obtain the same solution as in the book?

Comment: @Hiep you just get the transpose resulting in the same solution: $J^{'}(a) = a^TKK - t^TK + \lambda a^TK =((K+\lambda I)a-t)^TK=0$

Comment: I see my mistake. Thanks a lots!